# Fixing Apache-Camel Issue of Sockets Being Left in 'CLOSE_WAIT' State

Tags: java, apache-camel

This being my first foray into Camel I may be missing something obvious, so please be kind.

I am attempting to rectify the Camel issue that sees HTTP endpoints with dynamic URI elements leaving sockets in the CLOSE_WAIT state.

After viewing the issue and a potential fix/workaround within on [RedHat](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2695081), I am wanting to do as they say to fix my issues.

However I am unsure of how to properly implement on my code, as the Camel function `recipientList(...)` appears to be causing my issue.

recipientList is used due to endpoints depending on Exchange info (ie. the ID in the header), and `to()` only accepts static endpoint URIs.

**Problem code**

```
.when(/* ID header not null */)
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("PUT"))
    // This recipientList is causing the issue  
    .recipientList(simple(endpoint + '/' + ID_Placeholder + endpointParams))
    .end()
```

**Attempt to fix**

The documentation suggests the following solution:

> Rather than specifying the URI directly on the endpoint, use the
>   endpoint only to specify Camelparameters, and specify the URI using
>   the exchange header CamelHttpUri (In Java,Exchange.HTTP_URI).

It seemed to me that I should replace the `recipientList` line with the following:

```
.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, simple(endpoint + '/' + ID_HEADER_PLACEHOLDER + endpointParams))
```

However, I am unsure of how the data will then be distributed?

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant, but I know recipient list caches the endpoints - so if you have `uri:a` and `uri:b`, both will be cached by the camel context so it re-uses the cached endpoint rather than creating a new one each time you execute the route. You could try disabling this and see if the problem goes away. Have a look at: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/890313

Comment: @Screwtape I don't think this will impact my issue to be honest. The link I posted to the redhat source seems to suggest that it's more an issue of splitting the URI & Params into setting the URI with `.setHeader(MY_URI)` and sending the Params with `.recipientList(MY_PARAMS)`...

Comment: if I understand the solution correctly, what that will mean is that if you have multiple values for `MY_URI`, but only one version of `MY_PARAMS`, then Camel will only produce one endpoint object and keep re-using this, whereas otherwise it would keep an endpoint for each value of `MY_URI` up to the endpoint cache limit. If this is the case, then I would assume with this fix you'd get one socket left in the `CLOSE_WAIT` state instead of many.

Comment: @Screwtape I see what you mean. I am setting the set of URIs and params dynamically however, through the constructor. So I don't think the static param would be a problem, as I will be sending a specific set of params to a specific set of URIs. And as for perhaps having one open stream... I believe that would be more preferable to the current situation. Until a final fix can be implemented anyhow.